# PHP ERROR sqlsrv_fetch_array()

Tags: php

I got this error, try to solve it but can not find the problem:

> ERROR "Warning: sqlsrv_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\test3.php on line 14

SOURCE:

```
 <?php

   $serverName ="12.10.12.120";  $usr="myuser";  $pwd="myuser1"; 
   $db="Mydabb";

   $connectionInfo = array("UID" => $usr, "PWD" => $pwd, "Database" =>
   $db);

   $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);

   $sql = "SELECT Name, Address, Amount  FROM Order "; $res =
   sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql); while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($res))  
   {
       print($row['Name'].",".$row['Address'].",".$row['Amount']);  }  

   ?>
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: after `sqlsrv_query` add `if (!$res) die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));`

Comment: `ORDER` is a SQL reserved word. Use `[ORDER]` (edit).

Comment: @Fred-ii- it is MS sql, not mysql, in MS sql you should use `[` instead of backticks

Comment: @Lashane I stand corrected.

Answer (score 1):

`ORDER` is a SQL and [**MSSQL reserved word**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx) and must be wrapped in square brackets.

Change this line

```
$sql = "SELECT Name, Address, Amount  FROM Order ";
```

to

```
$sql = "SELECT Name, Address, Amount  FROM [Order] ";
```

or change the name for it, to "ORDERS" if possible.

You should enable error reporting, if would have signaled an error.

---

As stated in comments, place

```
if (!$res) die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
```

after `sqlsrv_query`

Answer (score 0):

There is probably an issue with the query itself as the function sqlsrv_query returns a boolean on an error.

From the documentation at:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-fetch-array.php

We see that before fetching the array the example first checks to see the return value of sqlsrv_query is equal to false and if it is then it will print the error with the sqlsrv_errors function and exit.

You will need to implement that to see what the error is so you can further debug.

```
 <?php

   $serverName ="12.10.12.120";  $usr="myuser";  $pwd="myuser1"; 
   $db="Mydabb";

   $connectionInfo = array("UID" => $usr, "PWD" => $pwd, "Database" =>
   $db);

   $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);

   $sql = "SELECT Name, Address, Amount  FROM Order "; 

   $res = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql); 

   if( $res === false) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
   }

   while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($res))  
   {
       print($row['Name'].",".$row['Address'].",".$row['Amount']);  }  

   ?>
```